# How do you arrange terminal color sequences into human friendly color grades

Tags: terminal, colors

I made this script to display terminal colors but the arrangement of colors I don't understand.

Here is the script which is pretty basic. It just increments the color code for the 256 color palette and arranges them in rows of 6.

```
#!/bin/env python3

def fg(n):
    assert -1 < n < 256, f"{n} value outside (0,255)"
    return f"\x1b[38;5;{n}m"

def bg(n):
    assert -1 < n < 256, f"{n} value outside (0,255)"
    return f"\x1b[48;5;{n}m"
    
RESET = "\x1b[0m"

print("The 1st 16 colors")
for i in range(0,16):
    print(f"{fg(0)}{bg(i)}[{i:03d}]{bg(0)}" , end = RESET)

print("\nthe rest\n")
for i in range(16,255,6):
    for j in range(0,6):
        print(f"{fg(0)}{bg(i + j)}[{i + j:03d}]", end = RESET)
    print()
```

Which outputs this grid and I think it could be better.

[image]

But I would like to know how can I arrange this in a more human friendly manor. Something similar to this grid below, where the colors are grades of the same hue. Is there some process to do that ?

[image]

The object of this is to be able to have a color grading function that can be applied to terminal coding.

Comment: You are generating the colours using RGB. Try using HSL/HSV instead. See [HSL and HSV - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Comment: @DavidPostill that was useful to me to understand what I was looking at and I got a range of values now for 6 color bars. I'm not sure if i sould answer the question or edit the question with the update.

Comment: You should answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @DavidPostill comment I understood I'm looking at layers of an RGB color block. So this answer, partially answers my own question. However, I had to cherry-pick the values of each hue into several lists, which I would rather encapsulate in function that could take 2 colors in the block and work out the tones in between.

To visualize the color block, here is a graphic that I labeled the corresponding terminal color code at each corner.

[image]

I realized that drawing a line from any number to any other number will give you a color gradient. The opposing corner to white (231) would be black (16).

Rearranging the terminal color grid this way it is easier to see that each layer is a slice of the 3D block above (going from left face to right face) and now is obvious how you can plot colors across and though this flattened block.

[image]

adding this code to my original code:

```
def print_color_range(name, clist):
    rangelen = len(clist)
    fore = fg(0) # black pen
    for i in range(rangelen):
        code = clist[i]
        back = bg(clist[i])
        print(f"{fore}{back}[{clist[i]:03d}]",  end = RESET)
    print(name)

WHITE_BLACK = [231,188,145,102,59,16]
WHITE_RED_BLACK     = [231,224,217,210,203,196,160,124,88,52,16]
WHITE_BLUE_BLACK    = [231,189,147,105,63,21,20,19,18,17,16]
WHITE_GREEN_BLACK   = [231,194,157,120,83,46,40,34,28,22,16]
WHITE_CYAN_BLACK    = [231,195,159,123,87,51,44,37,30,23,16]
WHITE_MAGENTA_BLACK = [231,225,219,213,207,201,164,127,90,53,16]
WHITE_YELLOW_BLACK = [231,230,229,228,227,226,184,142,100,58,16]
GREYS = [231,255,254,253,252,251,250,249,248,247,246,245,244,243,242,241,240,239,238,237,236,235,234,233,232,16]

print_color_range('reds', WHITE_RED_BLACK )
print_color_range('yellows', WHITE_YELLOW_BLACK    )
print_color_range('greens', WHITE_GREEN_BLACK  )
print_color_range('cyans', WHITE_CYAN_BLACK   )
print_color_range('blues', WHITE_BLUE_BLACK   )
print_color_range('magentas', WHITE_MAGENTA_BLACK)
print_color_range('white to black', WHITE_BLACK)
print_color_range('grays', GREYS)
```

produced this

[image]